# Wordpress Multisite unique redirect issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a unique issue with a multisite wordpress install.

Wordpress is installed in /blog/ folder on domain 1

domain 2 and domain 3 are using symlinks to connect to blog folder on domain 1

example:
domain2.com/blog symlink to domain1.com/blog

the unique issue i'm having is, if i go to http://www.domain2.com/blog everything works fine, but if i go to http://domain2.com/blog it redirects to domain1.com/blog

I've listed my .htaccess below for /blog folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I can't use Wordpress MU Domain Mapping plugin because its not in root folder.

Comment: so it sounds like a apache config issue. Make sure your domain2.com vhost also has `domain2.com` as a [ServerAlias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias)

Comment: The all do, i use serverpilot and its added by default. Both www.domain2.com and domain2.com work fine. Actually the non-www redirects to the www, just not when followed by /blog